# How to make a query that matches values within a specified range of non standard types?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

For standard ones I find it pretty straightforward

```
NumericRangeQuery.NewIntRange(item.Name, item.MinValue, item.MaxValue, true, true))
```

It works great with most common numeric types.
But what I would like to do is to make a range query with such datatypes as Date and decimal.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

For dates, store them as ints. So 2016 July 23 = 20160723
If you want to the hour or minute or second, just add those digits to the right. You may need to switch to long (Int64) for the longer versions.
If you want finer grain then store Ticks.
After all that just use the appropriate NumericRange query.

In Lucene.net 3.0.3 the best float accuracy is with Double